# Como extrair o caminho para o ficheiro

Tags: linux, variáveis, bash, path

Numa variável que contém o caminho para um ficheiro e seu respetivo nome, o nome do ficheiro pode ser extraído da seguinte forma:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
filenamepath="/caminho/para/ficheiro.pdf"
filename=$(basename $filenamepath)
```

O que nos resulta em `ficheiro.pdf` na variável `filename`.

Como podemos extrair apenas o caminho até ao referido ficheiro ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creio que isto seja o suficiente:

```
filenamepath="/caminho/para/ficheiro.pdf"
filepath=${filenamepath%/*}
```

Nota: por se tratar de tratamento de parâmetro do *bash*, não é "portável" para qualquer *shell*.

Se preferir uma solução análoga à da pergunta, usando comandos externos, temos o `dirname`, que é o "par natural" do `basename`:

```
filenamepath="/caminho/para/ficheiro.pdf"
filename=$(dirname $filenamepath)
```

Alternativamente, eis uma sintaxe usando o `sed` e demonstrando o uso dos *backticks*  para pegar o output de outro comando:

```
filenamepath="/caminho/para/ficheiro.pdf"
filepath=`echo $filenamepath  | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*|\1|' `
```